# открытие второй activity при нажатии на элемент списка

Tags: java, android, activity

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста на первой activity есть listview как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на первый элемент списка открывалась вторая activity?

**код первой формы:**

package com.example.admin.orshagoes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import static android.app.ProgressDialog.show;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String [] array;
    ListView listView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

    });

}
```

}

**код второй формы:**

```
package com.example.admin.orshagoes;
```

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class number_1 extends Activity {
    String [] arr;
    ListView listView1;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_1);
    arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1);
    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),arr[position] + ":" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, number_1.class));
    }
});
```

Comment: Не работает к сожалению ошибка этой строчке (this, number_1.class)

Comment: @Vitaliy, это была у вас ошибка компиляции - слушатель кликов - не активити, по этому просто this  не годится. См. исправленый ответ

Comment: Все отлично запустилось, НО пишет приложение остановлена при нажатии на элемент списка в чем может быть дело

Comment: @Vitaliy, перечисление всех причин займёт больше времени чем рассказ вами что за ошибка, где и приведения логов. И для этого можно отдельный вопрос задать)

Comment: Если вы ещё тут не подскажите как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на первый элемент открывалась 1 форма, а при нажатии на 2-ой - вторая и т. д.

Comment: @Vitaliy, на этот вопрос очень сложно ответить, т.к. реализовать можно тысячей способов. Есдинственное что можно сказать - в onItemClick есть параметр position - это порядковый номер элемента списка. Наверное он вам и нужен.